# JWT Laravel - Modifying the content of the json output

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, jwt

I'm trying to modify the json output of authenticate method of JWT in laravel to make it to display roles as an array.

So here i

> created_at
>   :
>   "2016-08-18 12:33:14"
>   email
>   :
>   "dhenn.espiritu@gmail.com"
>   id
>   :
>   1
>   last_logged_in
>   :
>   "2016-09-21 16:37:35"
>   name
>   :
>   "Dhenn"
>   roles
>   :
>   "{0: admin,
>   1: user"}
>   updated_at
>   :
>   "2016-09-21 16:37:35"

But I can't. I tried to modify my jwt.auth php file but it returned me an error that i am setting a non property object.

Here's current setup of the jwt-auth.php

```
public function authenticate($token = false)
{
    $id = $this->getPayload($token)->get('sub');

    if (! $this->auth->byId($id)) {
        return false;
    }

    $user = $this->auth->user();
    return $user;
}
```

While, I'm having error trying this:

```
 public function authenticate($token = false)
{
    $id = $this->getPayload($token)->get('sub');

    if (! $this->auth->byId($id)) {
        return false;
    }



    $user = $this->auth->user();

     foreach ($user as $roles) {
            $roles->roles = explode(",", $roles->roles);
        }
    return $user;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said this is your user object:

```
{ email : "dhenn.espiritu@gmail.com" 
  id : 1 
  last_logged_in : "2016-09-21 16:37:35" 
  name : "Dhenn" 
  roles : "{0: admin, 1: user"} 
  updated_at : "2016-09-21 16:37:35" }
```

Assuming `$this->auth->user();` returns this, your iteration `foreach ($user as $roles) {` is not correct, since `$user` should be an object not an array. This way you try to go through each property of this object, but I figure you want to iterate of the roles array.
This should be something like:

```
foreach($user->roles as $role) ... // assuming roles is an array
```

But `roles` seems to be a encoded JSON string, so you need to decode it too.

```
foreach(json_decode($user->roles) as $role) ...
```

Or directly: `$user->roles = json_decode($user->roles)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
protected $casts = ['roles' => 'array'];
```

to your User model. That should ensure that the attributes are parsed correctly.
Here is the link to the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

Comment: returning null on my end :(

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks all for your help. I figured out the answer.

Here's my code that worked finally.

```
public function authenticate($token = false)
 {
    $id = $this->getPayload($token)->get('sub');

    if (! $this->auth->byId($id)) {
        return false;
    }
    $user = $this->auth->user();
    $user->roles = explode(",", $user->roles);
    return $user;
 }
```

Comment: Now I see, what you wanted - the JSON encoded roles as list of role-objects. (See my updated answer above). Btw Kudos for coming back and showing your own solution!